# VBA Powerpoint - Combining normal text and equation inside a textbox

Tags: excel, vba, office365, powerpoint, equation

Trying to combine some normally written text and an equation (using the inbuilt insert equation feature inside powerpoint). It's quite easily done doing it manually by hand (type normal text, then click insert new equation or press alt and +), but with VBA proving tricky for me.

I've managed to do it in separate textboxes but when I try and do it together in one textbox, it formats all the text inside the textbox as an equation.

E.g. 'Solve 4x+2=8' I would want the 'solve' to be written as a normal string/text, however, the 4x+2=8 part I would like to be written using the powerpoint insert equation feature.

I've searched here and found this code to write an equation in a stand alone box. But when I add the world solve, it treats it like an equation and not normal text. I even tried to concatenate the 'solve' as a string.

```
Sub insert_equation()

Dim a As Integer
a = 2

Dim word As String

word = "Solve "

  Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("InsertBuildingBlocksEquationsGallery")

  With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame
  With .TextRange
      .Font.Size = 22
      .Text = word & "2x^2+7x+6=0"
      '.Text = a & "x"
  End With
  End With

  Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("EquationProfessional")

End Sub
```

In the picture below, the second textbox is what the code returns, the third textbox is what I hope to achieve. I would like to be able to have a mix of equations and normal text in various places within textboxes.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpxTr.png)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Sub WhatIsTheEquationMadeOf()
    Dim x As Long, txtBox As Shape
    word = "Solve "
    
    Set txtBox = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    If txtBox.Type = msoTextBox Then
        With txtBox.TextFrame.TextRange
            .Font.Color = RGB(80, 122, 160)
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignCenter
            .Font.Size = 22
            .Text = word & "2x^2+7x+6=0"
            .Characters(Len(word) + 1, .Characters.Count - Len(word)).Select
            With Application.CommandBars
                .ExecuteMso "InsertBuildingBlocksEquationsGallery"
                .ExecuteMso "EquationProfessional"
            End With
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

**Before**
[image]

**After**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way what i know, is using .Characters object.

```
Sub insert_equation()

Dim a As Integer
a = 2

Dim word As String

word = "Solve "

  Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("InsertBuildingBlocksEquationsGallery")

  With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters()
        .Font.Size = 22
        .Text = word
        .Font.Italic = False
        .Font.Color = vbRed
    End With

    With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(Len(word) + 1)
          .Font.Size = 32
          .Text = "2x^2+7x+6=0"
          .Font.Italic = True
          .Font.Color = vbBlue
    End With

  Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("EquationProfessional")

End Sub
```

You also can read about here [Characters object (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.characters)